# Stack Complexity of Pop operation

Tags: arrays, linked-list, stack, big-o

What is the Bog O notation of a pop() operation in a stack implemented with a Linked List?
What is the Bog O notation of a pop() operation in a stack implemented with an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a linked list, you can keep a pointer to the first and last elements of the list. Popping requires simply removing one of those and updating two (or three, if doubly linked) pointers: the one in the linked list, which is looking at the top element of the stack, and the one of the first element in the list. So `O(1)`, in this case.

With an array implementation, it depends. You could implement the pop operation as simply removing the last element in your array, and updating the size, which again would be `O(1)`. However, it is often the case that when an array implementation of a stack grows, then shrinks significantly, the items are moved to a new array in order to save memory (say, if you popped 10.000 times in a row and wanted that memory to not be unnecessarily held, then you could copy all the remaining items in a new, much smaller array). In that case, it would be `O(n)`, since each element would need to be copied over to a new array.